# How to make helm list all options when hitting M-x

Tags: org-mode, helm

I unfortunately lost my init_helm.el file, and had to reconstruct it from scratch, so far only with these commands:

```
(require 'helm)
(helm-mode 1)
```

The functionality I miss the most is the ability to list all alternatives when hitting M-x. Which code must I add to get this functionality back?

Comment: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki#preconfigured-helm-commands says to use `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)`

Comment: Hurray, that made it, the wonderful helm-list is back. Thanks : )